# Symfony2 bundle, show CAPTCHA only after few tries

Tags: symfony, recaptcha, orocrm

Is there are some bundle for Symfony2 (orocrm) bundle which show CAPTCHA (ReCAPTCHA better) only after few tries, not at first time after page loading. Or maybe there is another way to do that in symfony2.

Comment: I think that you need choose the right answer or delete question if you think that it is not helpful for community.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Session for this purpose. Just save your counter value in session variable and then compare it with your predefined value: if it is greater than your value use captcha if not - just increment your counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle i had to implement captcha recently and it was easy to implement and configure, you can try and if you have any question i can help